# Why are OpenGL functions loaded at runtime instead of dynamically linked?

Tags: opengl, dynamic-linking, dynamic-loading

Users of OpenGL APIs typically use a library such as GLEW or glad to load OpenGL functions at runtime. Why is dynamic loading the preferred linking method?

Static linking is clearly not an option since programs using OpenGL are typically compiled by the author and distributed to users who have different OpenGL libraries for their particular graphics cards.

That leaves dynamic linking and dynamic loading. It seems like dynamic linking could work since we know the names of all the functions we'll want to access.

Is dynamic linking a viable option? If not, why? If so, why is dynamic loading preferred?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you want is possible. You can make a loader that is a DLL/SO with a static interface, which will load function pointers from the implementation behind the scenes. It will pipe function calls to the implementation, based on which context is current. Indeed, this is essentially how modern Linux distros work.

This is also how WGL works on Windows... up though OpenGL version 1.1, at any rate.

The reason it is not "preferred" is because it requires effort. Someone has to create and *maintain* this intermediary library that sits between the application and the driver. Whenever a new extension comes out, the library has to be updated. Whenever a new version comes out, the library has to be updated. And then you have to make sure to link with the right version of this library.

That additional dependency worked out OK on Linux, because it was kept up to date. OpenGL32.dll on *Windows* however was not. WinNT adopted OpenGL for a while, but Microsoft had also gone off and <strike>created</strike>purchased their own graphics API for Win9x. So they never updated OpenGL32.dll for later OpenGL versions or new extensions. And if they were willing to be non-backwards compatible, I imagine they'd have ditched OpenGL32.dll entirely from their OS.

Since you need a runtime loader to work in Windows, it's easier to just make all platforms work using the same runtime loader (though obviously with a different function fetching the function pointers). And while you could create the kind of DLL you're talking about, it would just be one more OpenGL loading library, one more dependency you have to maintain. Without the centralization that Linux/MESA brings to the table, there's just no point in bothering.

---

> I was thinking that an application could be dynamically linked directly to the driver itself without an intermediate library

You can do that. However, you would be linking to that particular driver's library with a static import library. This means that if you link against NVIDIA's implementation, your application will fail to run on AMD's implementation.

And you can't statically link to import libraries for both DLLs. The reason being that if one static import library cannot be loaded, your application *terminates*. So unless you have *both* AMD and NVIDIA's implementations on your machine, you would not be able to run on either one.

Also:

> since even though the driver library can't be available at compile time, we still know the OpenGL function names

That assumes that their drivers directly *export* those names. That is hardly guaranteed.

After all, the WGL/GLX interface is to use `wgl/glXGetProcAddress` to get function pointers. If the interface between WGL/GLX and the driver is simply to pass the string to the driver's function, then the driver doesn't need to export any functions directly. It exposes its API through a single entrypoint, forcing runtime function pointer loading rather than allowing static linking.

> My understanding is that OpenGL loading libraries LoadLibrary/dlopen from dll/dylib/so library files which are themselves graphics card drivers and those driver libraries have symbol tables with OpenGL functions. Which parts of that are wrong?

All parts of that are wrong. You link against the basic interface API (like WGL or GLX). The loading library uses that interface to load function pointers. How the interface API translates loading a function pointer into the driver DLL is a platform-specific issue. On Windows, `wglGetProcAddress` calls a function in the driver, passing the string name of the function and getting back the function pointer.

On Linux, GLX tends to manufacture functions internally, using late-binding techniques to load the actual driver function later. That is, you can call `glXGetProcAddress` with some bogus name, and it will return a function pointer shim that, when called, will load the function for the current context from the driver.

Comment: I was thinking that an application could be dynamically linked directly to the driver itself without an intermediate library (since even though the driver library can't be available at compile time, we still know the OpenGL function names). It sounds like I completely misunderstand something about the nature of OpenGL or graphics card drivers. My understanding is that OpenGL loading libraries LoadLibrary/dlopen from dll/dylib/so library files which are themselves graphics card drivers and those driver libraries have symbol tables with OpenGL functions. Which parts of that are wrong? Thanks.

Comment: @Praxeolitic: And how do you know which DLL is the driver? Remember: when you link to a DLL via an import library, you will *always* load that specific DLL, and failure to load it will terminate your program. How do you know that the driver exports those function names with those *particular* names. Remember: you get function pointers via a third party: `wgl/glXGetProcAddress`, which may or may not be fetching exported functions directly. Linking directly to a driver's DLL can be done, but you would still have to query its function pointers at runtime, since it may not export them.

Comment: "After all, the WGL/GLX interface is to use wgl/glXGetProcAddress to get function pointers." I was unaware of this and this fact answers the question. There's simply a layer that forces this behavior and that's that. I suppose I could still ask why WGL and GLX do this but I now have to do some homework on WGL and GLX before that. Good answer.

Comment: "You can make a loader" - or use generator of loaders like [Implib.so](https://github.com/yugr/Implib.so).

Answer (score 1):

The OpenGL wiki gives some insight into the OpenGL [function loading process](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Load_OpenGL_Functions). Not that using the `GetProcAddress` functions amounts to a form of dynamic linking done outside of the operating system itself. From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_linker):

> In computing, a dynamic linker is the part of an operating system that loads and links the shared libraries needed by an executable when it is executed (at "run time"), by copying the content of libraries from persistent storage to RAM, and filling jump tables and relocating pointers.

Extensions for OpenGL come out all the time and can be either available or not depending on vendors and driver platforms. The OpenGL wiki states that on MacOSX:

> GL functions on OSX have been weak linked since OSX 10.2; this means that you can call them directly and unimplemented extensions will resolve to NULL. Note that this means that you must parse the extension string to determine if a function is valid or not, or your program will crash.

So even if Apple maintains a library to dynamically link with, you still need to add a layer to check whether a given function is available or not depending on the supported OpenGL version and extensions.

Comment: Checking if a function is available sounds like it's on the right track for answering this question but needs to be fleshed out more. Why is something other than the dynamic linking behavior of erroring out desired?

Comment: @Praxeolitic: Why would erroring out be desired? If an implementation doesn't provide an extension, and your application doesn't use that extension, your application is still fine.

Comment: To add to Nicol's comment, the application may have multiple ways to achieve a desired graphical output. Some of these may provide better performance but also depend on newer OpenGL features. For example, a texture blur could be done with compute shaders (faster) if they are available or rendering to a texture if not (broadly supported).

Comment: @NicolBolas The dynamic linker would error out if it's asked to look for a function that isn't available and in that case, erroring out would be desirable because your program needs to dynamically link a function that isn't available and that's an early showstopper.

Comment: @bernie That scenario does make sense.